# How to enable Autoboot for old MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, nvram

MacBooks released in and after 2016 have a feature that enables them to boot as soon as the lid is opened. I wanted to replicate the feature on my 2013 MacBook Air (MacOS Catalina Public Beta 5), so I read through this article: http://osxdaily.com/2017/01/19/disable-boot-on-open-lid-macbook-pro/
and entered the following command

```
sudo nvram AutoBoot=%03
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated in your post, this is a feature of various 2016 (and later) MacBook models, it is not supported on your 2013 MacBook Air.

I suppose you could get into the habit of putting your MBA to sleep instead of shutting it down, as this would mean it'd *start* fairly quickly upon opening the lid, but of course that's not the same as auto boot.